# Problems with tool tip in Flor BarChart

Tags: javascript, php, flot, bar-chart

i am using Flot API to plot data graphically in my application.I am able to plot data and i am able to achieve tool tip. But i am having a problem with tool tip.It is showing 'undefined' for label values along x axis.

```
$(function () {
            var a1 = [
        [0, 100],
        [1, 200],
        [2,300],
        [3,400],
        [4,500]

    ];
    var a2 = [
        [0, 80],
        [1, 150],
        [2,250],
        [3,360],
    [4,450]
        ];


        var data = [
            {
                label: "Pre Transformation",
                data: a1
            },
            {
                label: "Post Transformation",
                data: a2
            }



        ];

      $.plot($("#placeholder2"), data, {

            series: {
                bars: {
                    show: true,
                    barWidth: 0.13,
                    order: 1
                }
            },
            xaxis: {
            ticks: [[0,"Overall"],[1,"SEA"],[2,"INDIA"],[3,"NEA"],[4,"PZ"]],
            tickLength: 0
            },
                grid: {
          hoverable: true,
         clickable:true
  
         
          },

           valueLabels: {
                show: false
            }

       });

    });



 var previousPoint = null,
    previousLabel = null;

function showTooltip(x, y, color, contents) {
    $('<div id="tooltip">' + contents + '</div>').css({
        position: 'absolute',
        display: 'none',
        top: y - 40,
        left: x - 120,
        border: '2px solid ' + color,
        padding: '3px',
            'font-size': '9px',
            'border-radius': '5px',
            'background-color': '#fff',
            'font-family': 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif',
        opacity: 0.9
    }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
}


$("#placeholder2").on("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
    if (item) {
        if ((previousLabel != item.series.label) || (previousPoint != item.dataIndex)) {
            previousPoint = item.dataIndex;
            previousLabel = item.series.label;
            $("#tooltip").remove();

            var x = item.datapoint[0];
            var y = item.datapoint[1];

            var color = item.series.color;

          //console.log(item.series.xaxis.ticks[x].label);               

            showTooltip(item.pageX,
            item.pageY,
            color,
                "<strong>" + item.series.label+ "</strong><br>" + item.series.xaxis.ticks[x].label + ":  <strong>" + y + "</strong>");
        }
    } else {
        $("#tooltip").remove();
        previousPoint = null;
    }
});
```

I am facing problem with this line

```
"<strong>" + item.series.label+ "</strong><br>" + item.series.xaxis.ticks[x].label + ":  <strong>" + y + "</strong>"
```

If I remove .label from this item.series.xaxis.ticks[x].label i am getting tool tip
as Pre Transformation,undefined:100

```
Cannot read property 'label' of undefined
```

Please help me in this regards

Comment: Works good for me. Are you sure this is the code you are using? Check here: __http://jsfiddle.net/GGbyX__ and comment back if you have more problems again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tooltip for flot bar chart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21309955/tooltip-for-flot-bar-chart)

Comment: I am not showing stacked bar chart.If it is stacked bar chart it is working fine.But I am showing the bars in group.Check this fiddle.http://jsfiddle.net/ZRXP5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From you fiddle example I see you need the orderBar plugin. The [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZRXP5/) you posted in the comments uses a version of the plugin that I [adapted to Mootools](https://github.com/SergioCrisostomo/Mootools-chart-flot).

You want to use the jQuery version. [**You can find it here**](https://github.com/emmerich/flot-orderBars/tree/master/js). I advise you to store a local copy yourself.

And some things more:

**Besides the actual plugin** you need also to add some more info in your data. So add order info in your series also like:

```
    bars: {
        order: 1
    },
```

**To show the tooltip** and get the right index to the ticks object I would also change this part in your code:

```
var x = item.datapoint[0];
```

to:

```
var x = item.dataIndex;
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XrzYv/)